# CSS3 Custom tooltip fade in and out

Tags: html, css

I made custom tooltip, and before applying any CSS3 animation I displayed those tooltips using `display: none;` for hiding it, and `display: inline-block;` for showing tooltip. This works ok, but now I want to animate opacity of tooltip, so it have nice fade effect. But, I have problems with this, so I need your help. This is what I've tried:

```
.title div.tooltip{
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.title:hover div.tooltip{
    display: inline-block;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

and this is markup:

```
<li class="title">
<div class="tooltip">
<label><em>Full title:</em> <?php echo $groups['title']; ?></label><br>
<label><em>Description:</em> <?php echo $groups['description']; ?></label><br>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: JSfiddle required I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `filter: alpha(opacity=50);` and adding the `opacity:0;` to  `.title div.tooltip{...` worked for me.

The default for the opacity was 1, so the fade-in was going from 1 to 0.5 -- Also, I believe the `filter: alpha(opacity=50)` was overwriting the opacity transition completely and jumping right to opacity=50. You could also have added transitions for `filter`

```
.title:hover div.tooltip{
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.title div.tooltip{
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

see updated [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSegG/4/) - includes your complete css found in comments.

Comment: My apologies, my first attempt I believe I miss-understood. Did my edit cover the issue?

Comment: It works in jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MSegG/1/ but it doesn't work on my localhost, I really don't know what's the problem I don't have any other class .title or .tooltip

Comment: What is the HTML that your PHP is producing when you make the local URL call?

Comment: I also edited [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MSegG/4/) so the fade-in and fade-out would have similar styling (using your complete css).

Comment: I found error, it was one of my external jQuery plugins which blocks animations, I solved that but animation made some unwanted effects so I reverted it back to original values. Thank you for your help.